# WCF Compression in .NET 4 and IIS 7.5

Tags: wcf, iis-7, http-compression

Does enabling static and dynamic content compression in IIS 7.5 work for compressing .NET 4 WCF Services?

Curious if I still need to do this when using IIS 7.5 and .NET 4:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/169112/WCF-does-not-support-Compression-out-of-the-box-so?display=Print

Thanks -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it works. WCF 4 has new functionality ([see support for HTTP decompression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789.aspx)) which is automatically turned on by all standard HTTP based bindings. This functionality allows WCF based clients to automatically decompress incoming compressed responses.